# GUI - actionListener method

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I'm trying to create a simple GUI with a menu bar at the top of the jwindow using java. I'm able to get the menu bar to show and I'm able to implement the actionlistener class, however, how do I get the ok and ye tab, once clicked, to print out information? In other words how do I use the actionlistener class to create an action to print information out once ok or ye has been clicked by the user?

```
     // Creates a menu bar

    z.setJMenuBar(b);
    File.add(ok);
    File.add(ye);  
    Help.add(laws); 
    bar.add(HELP);       
    bar.add(FILE);

    // Listener objects created
    ok.addActionListener(this);
    ye.addActionListener(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are adding this like action listener the you should implement abstract method actionPerformed. You can do everything inside that method.